# Flutter: Is there way to scroll pageView programmatically while user scroll another pageView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

I have two PageViews in one screen (with different viewportFraction), I need to implement the next behavior: when a user scroll PageView 2, PageView 1, also need to be scroll with PageView 2. (Like safari tabs in iOS 15)

I would be very grateful for any hints on how to implement this behavior, maybe i can use some other widgets for this?

UPD: I have tried to use jumpTo, but it glitch. And if I scroll PageView 2 only to the half of page, PageView 2 automatically scrolls to next page

[image][image]

Comment: you need to setup a `PageController` to the other page view and use its `jumpTo` method

Comment: I have tried, but when i scroll, it glitch, because 1 PageView automatically want to scroll to some page position. Another words: if I scroll half of page, 1 PageView automatically scrolls back or to next page

Comment: post your code then

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you should maybe add controllers in your PageViews and then listen to the PageView2 controller

Like this:

```dart
    const Duration _duration = Duration(milliseconds: 100);
    
    final PageController _controller1 = PageController();
    final PageController _controller2 = PageController();
    
    _controller2.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _controller1.animateTo(_controller2.offset, duration: _duration, curve: Curves.ease);
      });
    });
```

PS: If your two PageViews have the same number of pages and the same width

Answer (score 0):

You should try out the loop page view  https://pub.dev/packages/loop_page_view
it's a pretty straightforward plugin

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:loop_page_view/loop_page_view.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final LoopPageController _controller = LoopPageController(initialPage: 0);

void gotToNextPage(int nextPage){

        _controller.jumpToPage(nextPage);
}

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Loop Page View Demo'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: LoopPageView.builder(
                controller: _controller,
                itemCount: 2,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('$index'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```